# Assembly: Delay using loops

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, delay, gpio

I'm trying to get an LED on Raspberry Pi to turn on/off with time intervals. I know there's a tutorial on how to do precisely that, but I was told that it's too complicated for the means of the program.

So a friend of mine gave me this code and told me that is can delay execution:

```
    /* using 3 loops for delay*/
for_i:
    mov r2, #0

next_i:
    cmp r2, #1000
    bge endfor    

for_j:
    mov r3, #0

next_j:
    cmp r3, #1000
    bge fin_i    

for_k:
    mov r4, #0
    cmp r4, #1000
    bge fin_j
    add r4, #1
    b for_k

fin_j:
    add r3, #1
    b next_j

fint_i:
    add r2, #1
    b next_i

endfor:
```

which as far as I understand is essentially 3 nested for-loops.

the bit of program I want to insert the delay looks like this:

```
loop$:

/*turn LED on*/
mov r5,#1
lsl r5,#16
str r5,[r4,#40]

*/insert delay*/

/*turn LED off*/
mov r5, #1
lsl r5,#16
str r5, [r4, #28]

*/insert delay*/

b loop$
```

When I cluelessly tried to insert loops somewhere in the code the LED just stayed on.
Honestly speaking, I don't have an idea how to insert this bit of code to get the program to be delayed or even if 3 loops will be enough to notice the interval.

The code to turn LED on/off should work perfectly fine, if I run the code without loop$, the LED stays off, and when I run the code with this loop, the LED is very dim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's simplify the code a bit. A little less branching should make it easier to see that it's actually three loops:

```
    mov r2, #0
next_i:
    mov r3, #0
next_j:
    mov r4, #0
next_k:
    add r4, #1
    cmp r4, #1000
    blt next_k
    add r3, #1
    cmp r3, #1000
    blt next_j
    add r2, #1
    cmp r2, #1000
    blt next_i
```

You can just paste that in your code where you want the delay.

If the LED glows dim, that suggests that the loop is way too short. Turning an LED on and off very fast is used to make it glow with different intensity.

Try changing one of the `#1000` to `#10000` to make the delay longer.

Comment: Thank you very much, turns out 1000 is pretty high for 3 loops. Now it works. Do you have any suggestion how to use those loop as a *method* to call from the code, rather than just copying it 2 times?

Comment: @user2407413: You can make it a subroutine: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Cihcfigg.html